# Is there an API for the Oscars/Academy Awards that lists past winners as well as current nominees?

Tags: api, film

I'm not looking for a page scraper but an actual API I can use that returns (preferably) JSON or XML. An example would be a request to return all the nominees for Best Picture in 2014.

The Oscar site itself has a page to search their database (http://awardsdatabase.oscars.org/ampas_awards/BasicSearchInput.jsp) but no API that I can find.

I've also looked into Rotten Tomatoes API (http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/JSON) but I didn't see any Oscar information that you could search for.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [**Wolfram Alpha API**](http://products.wolframalpha.com/developers/) for things like:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=academy+awards+1998

[image]

This is the free (public) interactive form interface. You can get a download as raw data with a Pro Subscriber (paid) license.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't seen any evidence of an API or official data set.

AggData.com has a [CSV of Oscar winners](http://aggdata.com/awards/oscar) from 1927-2010. Actually, they have two (see also [this](http://aggdata.com/free_data_awards_locations/academy_awards), which are similar but not the same. Both cover the same years and have the same row count, but I notice what looks like some CSV quoting issues from a little poking with `csvkit`. Also, frustratingly, the 'year' column is 'polluted' with which Awards, e.g. *1927/28 (1st)*

I also found [this blog post](http://blog.silk.co/post/78199230161/how-we-made-the-oscar-database) outlining a method for building [an Oscars database] from a few non-AMPAS sources. Unfortunately, they don't make the result of their work available for download.

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/User:Jobu0101:

> One of my goals is to represent the Academy Awards completely in
>   Wikidata. Each person, film, song, production company needs an item.
>   Each nomination and award has to be represented in Wikidata. Most of
>   the work was done until the Oscars 2016.

[This SPARQL query](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Academy_award_data) retrieves all the data about the Academy awards **winners**. One could split the query into small parts and use them as granular API operations. Or not so granular — in a GraphQL way.

Here below I "implement" a few operations of such an API, but for **nominees**.
In essense, I just replace `:P166` properties with `:P1411` ones.

---

**Get ceremony by year**

```
SELECT ?ceremony ?ceremonyLabel {
  VALUES (?year) {(1951)}
  ?ceremony wdt:P31 wd:Q16913666 .
  ?ceremony wdt:P585 ?date .
  FILTER (year(?date) = ?year) .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"}
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fceremony%20%3FceremonyLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fyear%29%20%7B%281951%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fceremony%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ16913666%20.%0A%20%20%3Fceremony%20wdt%3AP585%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28year%28%3Fdate%29%20%3D%20%3Fyear%29%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%20.%0A%7D)

```
|  ceremony   |    ceremonyLabel    |
|-------------|---------------------|
| wd:Q917076  | 23rd Academy Awards |
```

[This](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20%3Fceremony%20%3FceremonyLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20(%3Fyear)%20%7B(1951)%7D%0A%20%20%3Fceremony%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ16913666%20.%0A%20%20%3Fceremony%20wdt%3AP585%20%3Fdate%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20(year(%3Fdate)%20%3D%20%3Fyear)%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cen%22%20%7D%20.%0A%7D&format=json) is how JSON output looks like.

**Get categories by ceremony**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?category ?categoryLabel {
  VALUES (?ceremony) {(wd:Q917076)}
  [] ps:P1411 ?category ;
     pq:P805 ?ceremony .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"}
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcategory%20%3FcategoryLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fceremony%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ917076%29%7D%0A%20%20%5B%5D%20ps%3AP1411%20%3Fcategory%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20pq%3AP805%20%3Fceremony%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)

25 results, including:

```
|  category   |         categoryLabel          |
|-------------|--------------------------------|
| wd:Q103618  | Academy Award for Best Actress |
```

**Get nominated works by ceremony and category**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?work ?workLabel {
  VALUES (?ceremony) {(wd:Q917076)}
  VALUES (?category) {(wd:Q103618)}
  ?st pq:P805 ?ceremony .
    {
    ?st ps:P1411 ?category .
    ?st pq:P1686 ?work .
    }
    UNION
    {
    ?work p:P1411 ?st .
    ?st  ps:P1411 ?category .
    }
  ?work wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"}
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fwork%20%3FworkLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fceremony%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ917076%29%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fcategory%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ103618%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fst%20pq%3AP805%20%3Fceremony%20.%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fst%20ps%3AP1411%20%3Fcategory%20.%0A%20%20%3Fst%20pq%3AP1686%20%3Fwork%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fwork%20p%3AP1411%20%3Fst%20.%0A%20%20%3Fst%20%20ps%3AP1411%20%3Fcategory%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fwork%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%7D%0A%7D)

```
|    work     |    workLabel     |
|-------------|------------------|
| wd:Q193570  | Sunset Boulevard |
| wd:Q200299  | All About Eve    |
| wd:Q375594  | Born Yesterday   |
| wd:Q1451738 | Caged            |
```

**Get nominated people by ceremony, category and nominated work**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?personLabel {
  VALUES (?ceremony) {(wd:Q917076)}
  VALUES (?category) {(wd:Q103618)}
  VALUES (?work) {(wd:Q200299)}
  ?work p:P1411 ?st .
  ?st pq:P805 ?ceremony .
  ?st ps:P1411 ?category .
  ?st pq:P2453 ?person .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en"}
}
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fceremony%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ917076%29%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fcategory%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ103618%29%7D%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fwork%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ200299%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fwork%20p%3AP1411%20%3Fst%20.%0A%20%20%3Fst%20pq%3AP805%20%3Fceremony%20.%0A%20%20%3Fst%20ps%3AP1411%20%3Fcategory%20.%0A%20%20%3Fst%20pq%3AP2453%20%3Fperson%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22%7D%0A%7D)

```
|   person   | personLabel |
|------------|-------------|
| wd:Q228906 | Anne Baxter |
| wd:Q71206  | Bette Davis |
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else comes across this thread looking for a JSON of Oscar Best Picture winners, I've created a basic one for a mini project I'm working on which you can use as a starting point:

```
    const bestPictureWinners =
[
  {
    "name":"Wings",
    "releaseYear":"1927",
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Broadway Melody",
    "releaseYear":1928,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"All Quiet On the Western Front",
    "releaseYear":1930,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Cimarron",
    "releaseYear":1931,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Grand Hotel",
    "releaseYear":1932,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Cavalcade",
    "releaseYear":1933,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"It Happened One Night",
    "releaseYear":1934,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Mutiny on the Bounty",
    "releaseYear":1935,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Great Ziegfeld",
    "releaseYear":1936,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Life of Emile Zola",
    "releaseYear":1937,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"You Can't Take It With You",
    "releaseYear":1938,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Gone With The Wind",
    "releaseYear":1939,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Rebecca",
    "releaseYear":1940,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"How Green Was My Valley",
    "releaseYear":1941,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Mrs. Miniver",
    "releaseYear":1942,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Casablanca",
    "releaseYear":1942,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Going My Way",
    "releaseYear":1944,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Lost Weekend",
    "releaseYear":1945,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Best Years of Our Lives",
    "releaseYear":1946,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Gentlemen's Agreement",
    "releaseYear":1947,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Hamlet",
    "releaseYear":1948,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"All the King's Men",
    "releaseYear":1949,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"All About Eve",
    "releaseYear":1950,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"An American in Paris",
    "releaseYear":1951,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Greatest Show on Earth",
    "releaseYear":1952,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"From Here to Eternity",
    "releaseYear":1953,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"On the Waterfront",
    "releaseYear":1954,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Marty",
    "releaseYear":1955,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Around the World in Eighty Days",
    "releaseYear":1956,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Bridge on the River Kwai",
    "releaseYear":1957,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Gigi",
    "releaseYear":1958,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Ben-Hur",
    "releaseYear":1959,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Apartment",
    "releaseYear":1960,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"West Side Story",
    "releaseYear":1961,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Lawrence of Arabia",
    "releaseYear":1961,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Tom Jones",
    "releaseYear":1963,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"My Fair Lady",
    "releaseYear":1963,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Sound of Music",
    "releaseYear":1965,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"A Man for All Seasons",
    "releaseYear":1966,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"In the Heat of the Night",
    "releaseYear":1967,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Oliver!",
    "releaseYear":1968,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Midnight Cowboy",
    "releaseYear":1969,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Patton",
    "releaseYear":1970,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The French Connection",
    "releaseYear":1971,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Godfather",
    "releaseYear":1972,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Sting",
    "releaseYear":1973,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Godfather: Part II",
    "releaseYear":1974,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest",
    "releaseYear":1975,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Rocky",
    "releaseYear":1976,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Annie Hall",
    "releaseYear":1977,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Deer Hunter",
    "releaseYear":1978,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Kramer vs. Kramer",
    "releaseYear":1979,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Ordinary People",
    "releaseYear":1980,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Chariots of Fire",
    "releaseYear":1981,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Gandhi",
    "releaseYear":1982,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Terms of Endearment",
    "releaseYear":1983,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Amadeus",
    "releaseYear":1984,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Out of Africa",
    "releaseYear":1985,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Platoon",
    "releaseYear":1986,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Last Emperor",
    "releaseYear":1987,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Rain Man",
    "releaseYear":1988,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Driving Miss Daisy",
    "releaseYear":1988,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Dances with Wolves",
    "releaseYear":1990,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Silence of the Lambs",
    "releaseYear":1991,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Unforgiven",
    "releaseYear":1992,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Schindler's List",
    "releaseYear":1993,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Forest Gump",
    "releaseYear":1994,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Braveheart",
    "releaseYear":1995,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The English Patient",
    "releaseYear":1996,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Titanic",
    "releaseYear":1997,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Shakespeare in Love",
    "releaseYear":1998,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"American Beauty",
    "releaseYear":1999,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Gladiator",
    "releaseYear":2000,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"A Beautiful Mind",
    "releaseYear":2001,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Chicago",
    "releaseYear":2002,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
    "releaseYear":2003,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Million Dollar Baby",
    "releaseYear":2004,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Crash",
    "releaseYear":2004,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Departed",
    "releaseYear":2006,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"No Country for Old Men",
    "releaseYear":2007,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Slumdog Millionaire",
    "releaseYear":2008,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Hurtlocker",
    "releaseYear":2008,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The King's Speech",
    "releaseYear":2010,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"The Artist",
    "releaseYear":2011,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Argo",
    "releaseYear":2012,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"12 Years a Slave",
    "releaseYear":2013,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Birdman, or The Unexpected Virtue of Ignorance",
    "releaseYear":2014,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Spotlight",
    "releaseYear":2015,
    "seen":false
  },
  {
    "name":"Moonlight",
    "releaseYear":2016,
    "seen":false
  }
];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about APIs

Comment: the question isn't exactly clear regarding that...asks for API in title, then calls it a scraper in description. i get the feeling, i'm assuming @jonsanders101 did too, that all asker wanted was JSON.

Comment: yeah, the dataset fits into one reasonably sized JSON file, so making multiple calls to an API is probably overkill.

Comment: @albert Read again. I specifically mentioned I _didn't_ want a page scraper but instead a proper API so no one would suggest just writing a scraper of the Oscars search page.

Comment: yeah i missed that part, apologies. i've never heard of apis being confused with scrapers, but then again, i just misread your question.

Comment: Sorry - I realise this doesn't directly address the question, I just thought there was some value in sharing a JSON of the basic data, as that's how I (and presumably others) found this thread.

Answer (score 1):

data.world is hosting an Excel sheet that was scraped from the Oscar site:

https://data.world/graphhopper/2018-oscar-nominees

> Data came from the [official Oscars site](http://oscar.go.com/nominees), and was manipulated in Excel

The data is freely available, but if you register you can query the data with SQL.

And data.world has [integrations](https://data.world/integrations) with many programming and machine learning languages.

Answer (score 1):

I've mashed up a dataset based on Academy Awards winners and nominees on [Github](https://github.com/AminFadaee/awards/) which you can use like this:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AminFadaee/awards/master/academy_awards/93rd_academy_awards.json`

Comment: This is great, thank you, Amin