# Emmy Award winners

Tags: data-request, film, media

I'm looking for nominees and winners of the Emmys, but haven't found anything more structured than a Wikipedia article:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Primetime_Emmy_Award_winners

And a scraping-friendly list on the Emmys' website:

- http://www.emmys.com/awards/nominations/award-search

I've checked the IMDb [FTP dump](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) but didn't found any award data. I tried Wolfram Alpha (as described [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/is-there-an-api-for-the-oscars-academy-awards-that-lists-past-winners-as-well-as)); it shows only the Oscars.

Is there a machine-readable list of Emmys or only scraping can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dataset is not available, it could be useful in several projects and this Sunday evening was boring: three good reasons to scrape [this site](http://www.emmys.com/awards/nominations/award-search).

**[Here is the file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UQlbO0dPiCjj6kkjlK1Yu-CdCAYH8Y7I5VTBKGgPq3c/edit?usp=sharing)**

It contains the nominees and the winners from 1970<sup>*</sup> to 2016 (two sheets). Before merging both, I would prefer that someone take a look at it to check the data quality.

<sup>* I wonder why the scraper stopped in 1970, since the site contains information until 1949</sup>

Comment: You're welcome. I wonder why the scraper stopped in 1970, since the site contains information until 1949. I can take a look if these historical data are needed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an Emmy voter, an Open Data nerd, and a web developer -- and I don't know of a source.  Guess you're going to have to scrape the data, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to (have to) scrape this, take a look at [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org/) (formerly Google Refine). In their [second video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cO8NVCs_Ba0) they describe how to convert and massage a Wikipedia list.

The data on your Wikipedia page is a table, not a list, so it will be more complicated (especially, you'll have to deal with the different *colspans*).